# What kind of (1950s era) lock is this

Tags: doors, lock

My home, built in the late 1950s, has these cute little additional locks on top of the main doorknobs to many of the interior rooms.  I can't seem to find the correct term for these locks, which would allow me to find parts for them, etc., as several are broken.  Photo attached.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I have seen them referred to as a privacy latch.

Comment: Interesting.  A quick google image search turns up some things that function this way but nothing looks like them.  I realize they're old and no longer used.  Perhaps that's why. N

Comment: They're very cute locks.  But keep in mind if the door is latch, and there is any sort of emergency, you'll have to break the door down.  I see you have a child guard on the interior knob, and kids tend to lock themselves in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try a different search phrase as "Thumb Turn Security Latch".

There is a seller on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Door-Hardware-Lock-Mortise-Bolt-Thumb-Turn-latch-Security-ORB-SN-AB-PB-/350756041965) that has new stock available in range of finishes. Here is a picture of the offering.

[image]

Considering the price you may just want to consider purchasing new units instead of trying to locate parts for the old ones that are broken.

The trade name for these seems to be: Deltana mortise bolt

You can find those at many web sites including at [MyKnobs.com](http://www.myknobs.com/deltana-mortise-bolt.html).

Here are some dimensional pictures from a Deltana specification sheet so you can compare to your existing items.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  That did it.  At $15, I'm just going to replace the bad ones.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: They can be used on outside doors, as deadbolt.  They're not ideal, because you can't unlock them from the outside (also a concern indoors, with children)